# Why does a charlist not get displayed as a list?

Tags: elixir

I am trying to iterate a charlist with the `Enum.map` function, but it does not behave how I would expect it to behave.

The first line does not treat the charlist as a list of chars, and in the second line I do not understand why modifying the anonymous function does it.

```
iex(32)> Enum.map('ABCD',fn(char)->char end)  
'ABCD'
iex(33)> Enum.map('ABCD',fn(char)->[char] end)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I was expecting the first line to return `['A','B','C','D']` and the second line to return `[['A'],['B'],['C'],['D']]`. Why isn't this the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Elixir, and not only (for example C also) char is a number, which represents ASCII code of a "character". Also, `'` brackets represent a list, while `"` represents binaries (or **strings**).

So, this code probably will help you understand what is going on:

```rb
iex> is_list('ABCD')
true # it's list - as described    
iex> is_binary('ABCD')
false # it's list of chars - not a string
iex> is_binary("ABCD")
true # with " brackets it's a string
iex> is_list('A')
true # Of cource this is list - list with one element. Like [65]
iex> [65]
'A' # Unexpected? As I told - char is a simple integer!
iex> [65, 66, 67, 68]
'ABCD' # Absolutely logical from previous line
iex> ?A
65 # We use ? sign to get "char" from "letter"
iex> [?A | 'BCD']
'ABCD' # List append works as expected
iex> [?A | [66, 67, 68]]
'ABCD' # The same - absolutely
iex> Enum.map('ABCD',fn(char)->char end)  
'ABCD' # char "variable" here is 65, 66, 67, 68 -> maps into list [65, 66, 67, 68]
iex> Enum.map('ABCD',fn(char)->[char] end)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # You've got list of lists here. Quite crazy?
iex> [[65], [66], [67], [68]]
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] # This is your list
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok found it... This is caused by iex that display in a user friendly way the char list.
If I use the settings:

```
iex(1)> IEx.configure(inspect: [charlists: :as_lists])
```

Then it display the real output :)

Comment: You can blame erlang for this state of affairs.  It's nice that iex has the `:charlists` option.  The key thing to remember in elixir is 'abc' is shorthand for `[97,98,99]`.

Comment: “Real output” is a very wrong wording, though. `'ABC' == [65, 66, 67] #⇒ true`, so both outputs are exactly equivalent, there is no _real_ one. `'ABC'` **is indeed a list**. What you have expected in the question is not what `charlists: :as_lists` provides.